# document() method problem in xsl processing by javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, webkit, xmlhttprequest, xslt

My problem is WebKit cannot handle xslt document() method when i use javascript to do xslt processing. When I include xsl file in xml and call xml file from browser it work. But when I use javascript to handle this process, it crashes. I have to use javascript to pass parameters to xsl file. So I cannot live without javascript.
Here is html part.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" src="./js/jquerymin.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="./js/jquery.transform.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example").transform({xml:"sample.xml", xsl:"sample.xsl", xslParams:{scan:'system',sub:'lan'}});
});
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="example" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here  is basic xsl file which crashes with this approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:nsm="http://xxxxx.com/yyyyy/system"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:param name="scan" select="'system'"/>
<xsl:param name="sub" select="'lan'"/>

<xsl:output method="html"/>  

<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="xsdFile" select="document('sample.xsd')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$xsdFile">
               ssss
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As I said it does not work while I let javascript to do transformation.But when I call xml file from browser it works.

Is this a bug or I miss something here?

Thanks,

edit: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Transform this is the jquery plugin I use. By the way other browsers such as firefox and opera can handle both ways quite perfect

Comment: @savruk: The only workaround is to pass the document as parameter.

Comment: @Alejandro Can I apply xpath on this paramater? Because I pass the document from javascript. and let say when I use `xsl:value-of select="$xsdfile"` it displays the xsd file contents. but i cannot apply xpath on it like
`$xsdfile/xs:schema/child::*`

Comment: @savruk: If that is the case, you are not passing a node set parameter. Maybe a string? Check your XSLT processor documentation to see how to pass node set as parameters.

Comment: @Alejandro No differences. I was able to send as node set. But again it does not work on WebKit. When i use `<value-of select="$xsd"/>` it prints `[object Document]` on webkit and nothing on others. but when i use `<value-of select="$xsd/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='info']"/>` it gives the expected output on others but not on WebKit

Comment: @savruk: If the XPath expression (more precisely the `/` operator)works on others, it means that you are passing a node set **for others**. If the XML Schema document doesn't have text nodes, then the correct string value would be an empty string, never would be `[object Document]` unless Webkit is casting the parameter to string and that operation on `Document` objects result in such string.

Comment: @savruk: The official bug report https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14101

Comment: @Alejandro Thank you. So I was doing good but it is a problem of webkit. And it's been there for 3 years. what a shame. Thanks very much again

Comment: And this is the official bug report of my first approach which is using "document" method.https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10313

Comment: @savruk: You might find interesting my old XML/XSLT driven site at aranedabienesraices.com.ar without any of this javascript problems.

Comment: @Alejandro when I try to open your site with Arora(webkit engine) it only shows me "ARANEDA Bienes Raices "Esta es la llave que abre la puerta de su nuevo hogar" # #".

Comment: @savruk: I didn't test in Arora. It's tested and working on Chrome and Safari. It looks like your Arora browser has `document()` function disable... let me see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bug 14101 - XSLTProcessor does not accept Nodes as parameter values](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14101)

I've been waiting for the WebKit team to fix this bug for quite a while (it's been open since mid-2007).

If somebody knows of a way to expedite this fix please chime in.

Answer (score 1):

Alejandro, to work `document()` in XSLT you need use the server-side of the transform plug-in