# Reading multiple xml files does not return a value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have 2 xml files and I want to read data from both files in one xsl transformation. I try to read the data from the second file using the document() function, but it does not return any value.

**XSL template**

```
<xsl:template name="BuildingList" match="building">
    <xsl:variable name="allBuildings" select="document('buildings.xml')/buildings"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$allBuildings" />
</xsl:template>
```

**Buildings.xml structure**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<buildings>
    <building id="First">
        <title>Some title</title>
    </building>
</buildings>
```

How can I get the content in order to manipulate it?

EDIT:
All three files are in the same directory. I tried to process the transformation with the following two jQuery plugins:

- [Transform](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Transform)
- [xsltParser](http://jquery.bwit.se/xslt-parser/demo.html)

With either of them the transformation of more than one file is not working.

**Using the pluings:**

```
function LoadContent(pageName)
        {
            var currentPage = pageName+ '.xsl';

            $.transform({el:"#information",xml:"pages.xml",xsl:currentPage});

            /*$('#information').xsltParser({
                xml:  'pages.xml',
                xslt: currentPage,

                onStart: function() {
                    //$('#log').append('Preparing... ');
                },
                onSend: function(url) {
                    //$('#log').append('Requesting ' + url + '... ');
                },
                onComplete: function() {
                    //$('#log').append('Done!');
                }
            });*/
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `document()` is not supported in client-side transformation as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312179/document-method-problem-in-xsl-processing-by-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Well where are the two files in relation to each other and in relation to the stylesheet? Does `select="document('buildings.xml', /)/buildings"` give better results? It could if the stylesheet is in a different location than the primary input document.

Comment: The two files are in one and the same directory. The first document lists information for pages and the buildings.xml files list the data for a specific page. The suggested piece of code does not work

Comment: You need to provide more information to allow us to reproduce the problem. For instance some XSLT processor by default disable stuff like `document` for security reasons. So tell is exactly which your XSLT processor is, how you run the transformation, how you look at the result. Otherwise we keep guessing.

Comment: Teddy, please answer Martin's question: "where are the two files in relation to each other and in relation to the stylesheet?"

Comment: The two files are in one and the same directory as well as the stylesheet file.